# Calculate and display the sum of the first 20 numbers in Fibonacci series

Tags: python

```
    terms = int(input("Enter the terms: "))

x, y = 1, 2
count = 0
sum = 0.0

if terms <= 0:
   print("Please enter a positive integer")
elif terms == 1:
   print("Fibonacci sequence upto",terms,":")
   print(x)
else:
   print("Fibonacci sequence:")
   while count < terms:
       sum = z + x + y
       print(x,end=" ")
       z = x + y
       x = y
       y = z
       count += 1
   print("The sum of Fibonacci sequence:",sum)
```

'The error is the program cant defined the z and cant display the sum. Is that i put the sum code in wrong place?'

Comment: Why is `sum = z + x + y` before `z = x + y` ? What should `z`  be before `z = x + y` is executed?

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
sum = z + x + y
```

you have not defined z.
Try this

```
x, y, z = 1, 2, 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you are simply using z variable before even initializing it. The program doesn't know z exists and you are trying to use it to calculate sum.
first you need to initialize z and then use it to calculate sum.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should replace "sum" with another name, try "summation"
2. Since you didn't defined z in first 14 lines, you can't use it in line 15. You should define z before using it.
3. Your sum calculation is not correct at all.